# Newtheorem and pausing

Tags: beamer, pause, newtheorem

I'm working through the Beamer tutorial at http://web.mit.edu/rsi/www/pdfs/beamer-tutorial.pdf, partly because it has enough errors in it to force me to learn things a bit more deeply.  My current problem is sequencing Theorems created with \newtheorem.  In the attached code (the simplest I can think of to illustrate the problem), the compile step fails with this error:

```
./mit_tut.tex:17: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \saved@c@thm
l.17 \end{frame}
```

The error can be avoided by commenting out the \pause line, but of course then I lose the sequencing I want.  It also doesn't matter if I use sequencing numbers like this:

```
\begin{thm}<1->
```

Can you point out to me what I'm missing?  Or direct me to another solution that achieves the desired effect?

The entire file:

```
% Reference: http://web.mit.edu/rsi/www/pdfs/beamer-tutorial.pdf
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{}
\begin{document}

\title{The Title}
\begin{frame}{Math Stuff}
\newtheorem{thm}{Easy Theorem}
\newtheorem{pf}{Proof}
\begin{thm}
  Blah, blah
\end{thm}
\pause
\begin{pf}
  Yade, yade
\end{pf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! You probably need neither `\mode<presentation>{}` nor `[pdf]`.

Answer (score 3):

Define your new theorems already in your preamble:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newtheorem{thm}{Easy Theorem}
\newtheorem{pf}{Proof}

\title{The Title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Math Stuff}
\begin{thm}
  Blah, blah
\end{thm}
\pause
\begin{pf}
  Yade, yade
\end{pf}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```